# Listing all combination of list 1 to n given length restriction k

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found a code that recursively returns all combination of a list of 1 to n numbers with length k

```
def choose_iter(elements, length):
    for i in range(len(elements)):
        if length == 1:
            yield (elements[i],)
    else:
        for next in choose_iter(elements[i+1:len(elements)], length-1):
            yield (elements[i],) + next
def choose(l, k):
    return list(choose_iter(l, k))
```

this will return what I need but can I modify this so that I dont have to use the yield function? I haven't studied yield yet and I don't want to confuse myself with this.

Comment: I am sorry I think that was a typo on my part

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `itertools`:

```py
import itertools
for combination in itertools.combinations([i for i in range(1, n+1)], k):
    print(combination)
```

For `n=7` and `k=5`, you have:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 6)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 7)
(1, 2, 3, 5, 6)
(1, 2, 3, 5, 7)
(1, 2, 3, 6, 7)
(1, 2, 4, 5, 6)
(1, 2, 4, 5, 7)
(1, 2, 4, 6, 7)
(1, 2, 5, 6, 7)
(1, 3, 4, 5, 6)
(1, 3, 4, 5, 7)
(1, 3, 4, 6, 7)
(1, 3, 5, 6, 7)
(1, 4, 5, 6, 7)
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
(2, 3, 4, 5, 7)
(2, 3, 4, 6, 7)
(2, 3, 5, 6, 7)
(2, 4, 5, 6, 7)
(3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: Can I do it without having to use itertools?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be the correct code

```
def choose_iter(elements, length):
    for i in range(len(elements)):
        if length == 1:
            yield (elements[i],)
        else:
            for j in choose_iter(elements[:len(elements)], length - 1):
                yield (elements[i],) + j
def choose(l, k):
    for i in choose_iter(l, k):
        print(i)
```

yield is similar to return but in this case, you need the yield statement otherwise the code will not work. You can check
[What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)
for more info.

And also avoid using "next" as a variable because it's also a python function.

Hope I helped.